# RRuntimeError when running a user defined function using rpy2 in python

Tags: python, rpy2

I defined a function using rpy2, but it went wrong, the code is in below:

```
import rpy2.robjects as ro
ro.r("""#create a function `f`
f <- function(r, verbose=False){
if(verbose){
    cat（"I am calling f().\n"）
}
2 * pi * r
}
f(3)
""")
```

p = _rparse(text=StrSexpVector((string,)))

RRuntimeError

I copied the code in the [document](https://rpy2.github.io/doc/v2.9.x/html/introduction.html), I don't know where is wrong.